# unable to see remote system video on my screen

Tags: opentok, video-conferencing

Do you have any demo on video confrencing. I just created a code but unable to see remote computer video on my screen and my video on remote system screen.

here is my code

```html
<head runat="server">
<script src="//static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/opentok.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
    var apiKey = "Key";
    var sessionId = "*session*";
    var token = "*token*";

    var publisher = TB.initPublisher(apiKey, 'myPublisherDiv');
    var session = TB.initSession(sessionId);

    session.addEventListener('sessionConnected', function (e) {
    session.publish(publisher);
    for (var i = 0; i < e.streams.length; i++) {
        if (e.streams[i].connection.connectionId == session.connection.connectionId) {
            return;
        }
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('id', 'stream' + e.streams[i].streamId);
        remoteVideo.appendChild(div);
        session.subscribe(e.streams[i], div.id);
    }
    });

    session.addEventListener('streamCreated', function (e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < e.streams.length; i++) {
        if (e.streams[i].connection.connectionId == session.connection.connectionId) {
            return;
        }
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute('id', 'stream' + e.streams[i].streamId);
        remoteVideo.appendChild(div);
        session.subscribe(e.streams[i], div.id);
    }
    });
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="myPublisherDiv" style="width:320px; height:240px; background-color:#ffffff"></div>
<div id="remoteVideo" style="width:320px; height:240px; background-color:#ffffff"></div>
</form>
</body>
```

Can you provide any demo or resolve the error in this code.
unable to see remote system video on my screen.

manish

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code for you. You seed to be using an older version of the API. Here's some sample code for group video chat. Be sure to replace apiKey, sessionId, and token with your own credentials. Good luck!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

  <script src='//static.opentok.com/webrtc/v2.2/js/opentok.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    var apiKey = "apiKey";
    var sessionId = "sessionId";
    var token = "Token";

    var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
    session.connect( token, function(err){
      if(!err){ session.publish(); }
    });
    session.on("streamCreated", function(event){
      session.subscribe( event.stream );
    }); 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```